# Spring Boot REST JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, rest, spring-mvc

I have a working Spring BOOT application that has a custom security provider and REST API controllers. I would also like to add a GUI interface to the application for access from a browser through jsps, html, and a login page which uses my existing custom security provider I used with the REST APIs.  Maybe using Spring MVC since that is needed for the REST API support. I could not find a single example of doing this on the web. Also, I do NOT want to use any web XML based configuration files - as I am currently only using Java config for the implementation of the REST APIs. I am also currently using SSL for REST API access through SSL in a Jetty embedded web container. Please help if you can? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Paul there is a rather large amount of information on view technologies that are compatible with Spring BOOT. You need to decide what you want to use and do relevant research for it.

As a guiding hand here check this page out for just one of the many types:

http://kielczewski.eu/2014/04/spring-boot-mvc-application/

Comment: The thing that I got caught on was your rest controllers need `@RestController` so the returned Strings don't get converted into views, and your view controller get `@Controller`.

Comment: @TomSaleeba,i have also encountered the same issue and have decided to go with the approach u have mentioned above.basically my REST controllers endpoints start with /api whereas my view endpoints doesnt have /api with Rest and Normal controllers accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You may follow this procedure :

lets assume that u have an endpoint for which you need both REST and view controllers,your REST endpoint exposes your data in JSON as RESTController and your view Endpoint returns the view name as Simple old controller.

lets say your base url is at localhost:8080 and your endpoint of interest is /students

you could have both in same application but at different endpoints like this :

```
 REST : localhost:8080/api/v1/students -- exposes json 
 VIEW : localhost:8080/students -- returns a view
```

hope this make clear ..